# Fourier transform of a tempered distribution on a semiaxis

Tags: reference-request, distribution-theory

It is well known that the Fourier transform is well defined on the class of tempered distributions on the real line. It is easily seen that the Fourier transform of a tempered distribution, whose support lies on the positive semiaxis, defines a holomorphic function in the upper halfplane of the complex plane. My question is as follows:

*Given a holomorphic function on the upper halfplane, how to decide whether it is the Fourier transform of a tempered distribution supported on the positive semiaxis?*

I am sure the answer is well known, but I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: Say $f$ is your function, and let $f_y(x)=f(x+iy)$. I _conjecture_ that $f$ is a Fourier transform as above if and only if the family $\{f_y\}_{y>0}$ is bounded in $S'$, in the topological-vector-space sense.

Comment: This looks like the condition on the existence of the limit as $y\to 0$. Indeed, it might be equivalent. I am looking for a more explicit condition, if it exists.